# if fun1 done do fun2, else dont do fun2

Tags: c#, function

I'm working on C# project, so I have 2 functions, I just need if function1 has been done then I want the function 2 execute, else function 2 must be prevent to executed (Didnot Execute!!).

My Function 1 called `SaveDuplicatCourse()` and function 2 called `Save()`, the code for each other as below:

```
public void SaveDuplicatCourse()
{
   if(con.State !=ConnectionState.Open)
      con.Open();
   List<int> IDs = new List<int>();
   foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridViewStudents.Rows)
   {
      if (r.Cells[0].Value != null && bool.Parse(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
      {
         IDs.Add(int.Parse(r.Cells[1].Value.ToString()));
      }
   }
   foreach (int i in IDs)
   {
      try
      {
         SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into DuplicateCourses 
                                           values(" + i + "," + CCID + ")", con);
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("They are exist");
      }
   }
   con.Close();
}

public void Save()
{
   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"Delete from students 
                                     where 
                                     Course_ID = " + ID, con);
   con.Open();
   com.ExecuteNonQuery();

   List<int> IDs = new List<int>();
   foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridViewStudents.Rows)
   {
      if (r.Cells[0].Value!=null && bool.Parse(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
      {
         IDs.Add(int.Parse(r.Cells[1].Value.ToString()));
      }
   }

   foreach (int i in IDs)
   {
      com.CommandText = "Insert into students values(" + i + "," + ID + ")";
      com.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   con.Close();
}
```

I called these function in `ButtonClick` as below

```
private void buttonSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SaveDuplicatCourse();
   Save();
}
```

Please tell me how it will be done.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. `unexecuted`?? what the...?

Comment: Make those functions return bools instead of void.

Comment: return `bool` on the first function? `if (Func1()) Func2();`

Comment: I just need `Save();` to execute only if `SaveDuplicatCourse()` has been done, that is all

Comment: And thats exactly what you're doing right now - they're not being executed in parallel.

Comment: It will be done. You are not worried about `con.Open();      com.ExecuteNonQuery();` either, are you?

Comment: but `Save()` execute even `SaveDuplicatCourse();` did not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `boolean` value to function1.  If it returns false, don't run function2.  If it returns true, run function2.

```
boolean saveDuplicateCourseCompleted = false;

private void buttonSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (saveDuplicateCourseCompleted == true)
      Save();
   else
      // or do something else.        
}
```

Note the example below:

```
public boolean SaveDuplicatCourse()
{
    if(con.State !=ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Open();
    List<int> IDs = new List<int>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridViewStudents.Rows)
    {
        if (r.Cells[0].Value != null && bool.Parse(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
        {
            IDs.Add(int.Parse(r.Cells[1].Value.ToString()));
        }
    }
    foreach (int i in IDs)
    {
       try
       {
          SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into DuplicateCourses 
             values(" + i + "," + CCID + ")", con);
          com.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("They are exist");
          saveDuplicateCourseCompleted=false// Now this is right way
       }
    }
    con.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, i don't see anything that is occurring asynchronously, so your code should execute in the fashion you are looking for. Now, if you are asking about executing successfully (as opposed to whatever unsuccessful may be, ie no rows deleted), that is a different story, and can be handled in a variety of different fashions. But before we go down that road, it seems you are already getting the desired result. Set a breakpoint and step through each line of code to watch the order of execution.